# Can I use MongoDB 3.6 or later with Unity 2018.4?

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm trying to apply the MongoDB with [this unity tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tc5raxEFntw) MongoDB bought mLab, so the signing into mongoDB is done via mongoDB atlas. And they only support MongoDB 3.6 and later.

I've created a cluster with **AWS** (similarly to the GUI mLab has),

- On "Overview" tab hit the "CONNECT" button. Out of the three options: "Connect with the Mongo Shell" / "Connect Your Application" / "Connect with MongoDB Compass" - Connect Your Application looked the most relevant to the code you've provided.
- In: "Connect Your Application" you need to choose a driver: I chose C# / .NET (because this is a C# project), version 2.5 or later.
- Got "Connection string": `mongodb+srv://user_name:<password>@testmp-pkump.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`

Few things:

1. The project name is not "test" (as it says here, right before the retryWrites = true): mongodb+srv://:@testmp-pkump.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
2. I've passed this link to the code under: private const string MONGO_URI , and for user name I write the user I've added to the cluster, and for the password, I write the password I've added to the user in the cluster. - and not the user I've used to create the MongoDB account
3. Running the "Server" scene resolves with an error: =

```
ArgumentException: Invalid keyword 'mongodb+srv://:@serverclientmp-
1oqao.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retrywrites'.
MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item (System.String 
keyword, System.Object value)
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionStringNonOdbc 
(System.String connectionString) 
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionString 
(System.String connectionString) 
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString 
(System.String value) MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder..ctor 
(System.String connectionString) 
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.ParseConnectionString (System.String 
connectionString) MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor (System.String 
connectionString) Mongo.Init () (at Assets/Scripts/Database/Mongo.cs:16) 
Server.Init () (at Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:40) Server.Start () (at 
Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:28)
```

I've tried to change the API Compatibility Level to .NET 4.x and the following error came:

```
ArgumentException: Invalid option 'retryWrites'.
Parameter name: url
MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse (System.String url) (at 
<6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder..ctor (System.String url) (at 
<6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor (System.String url) (at 
<6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.ParseConnectionString (System.String 
connectionString) (at <6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0)
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor (System.String connectionString) (at 
<6da29fc855c44d33ad78b3e27475ff27>:0)
Mongo.Init () (at Assets/Script/Database/Mongo.cs:15)
Server.Init () (at Assets/Script/Server.cs:38)
Server.Start () (at Assets/Script/Server.cs:27)
```

I would like to know what I need to add to my scripts to make it work or if this tutorial is outdated and a new approach needs to be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know I am 8 months too late but, I have recently began working with MongoDB in Unity and I don't know if this will help but the short answer is **I'm not sure**. But I managed to connect to my remote and local db, so I'll explain how I did it below.

---

**The Long answer:**

I did not watch the tutorial video you followed but i setup my connections with these [dll files](https://github.com/Julian23517/Unity-mongo-csharp-driver-dlls) (I am assuming you also created a **Plugins** folder for them). As for the "tutorial", I simply followed this quick start [guide](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-c-sharp-and-mongodb-starting-and-setup) and this [one](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/getting_started/quick_tour/). Everything else API related I just read the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/R_Project_CSharpDriverDocs.htm).

- I'm using **MongoDB** **v4.2.1**
- I'm using **Unity 2019.3**
- I'm using **API compatibility .Net Standard 2.0**
- I'm using the **admin user** on the cluster. I don't know what your case is but I remember the documentation says that your user should have read and write privileges, so check that maybe.

Finally, I had an error when I first tried to connect to the remote DB, but maybe because I have my code wrapped around a try catch block, it didn't produce the error you provided but rather this:

```
Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1 mongo c# driver
```

Which occurred because I forgot to take the angle brackets out of the code and had this instead - <password> - yes I left my password wrapped around the brackets, rookie mistake lol.

---

Here's how I connected to my Atlas cluster:

```
private const string remoteDB = "mongodb+srv://user_name:<password>@mycluster.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
static MongoClient newClient = new MongoClient(remoteDB);

internal Database()//This is a constructor, I'm not using MonoBehaviour
{
    db = newClient.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    lbCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(lbColl);
    gameStateCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(gameStateColl);
}

internal static async Task TestConnection()
{
    try
    {
        await GetDBNames();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("<color=red> Error</color> found while testing db connection:");
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}

private static async Task<List<string>> GetDBNames()
{
    List<string> dbNames = new List<string>();

    var dbs = await newClient.ListDatabaseNamesAsync();
    dbNames = dbs.ToList();

    if (dbNames.Count > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Databases in {nameof(dbNames)}: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < dbNames.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{dbNames[i]}");
        }
        
        return dbNames;
    }

    Debug.Log($"<color=red>{nameof(GetDBNames)}</color> Returning null. No Dbs found.");
    return null;
}
```